# Angularjs ui grid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-scope

```js
catsUser.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','uiGridConstants','$interval', function ($scope, $http,uiGridConstants,$interval) {

 $scope.resultSummary=true;
  
   $scope.getEventJson=function(){
    
    $http.get('ui/app/components/cpf/user/data/JsonDataForGrid.json').then(function(response){
     console.log(response)
     $scope.EventList=response.data;
     $scope.CreateGrids();
     
    })
   }
  
   $scope.getEventJson();

  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.gridapis=[]
  $scope.CreateGrids = function() {

   var count=0;
   angular.forEach($scope.EventList,function(Evt){
      var eventData = "griddata" + count;
      $scope.data[eventData] = [];
      $scope.data[eventData] = {
        enableRowSelection: false,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableColumnResizing: true,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        enableFiltering: false,
        enableCellEditOnFocus:true,        
        multiSelect: true,
        data:Evt.record,
        columnDefs:Evt.col
     
      };  
      count++;
      
      
      $scope.data[eventData].onRegisterApi=function(gridApi){
       
       console.log("ON REGISTER API FOR GRID:"+eventData);

       var k=eventData.slice(-1);
       $scope.gridapis[k]=gridApi
       
       
     //Listener to change the color
       gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity,colDef,newval,oldval){
           colDef.cellClass = function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
                 if (rowEntity.EventID === row.entity.EventID &&newval !== oldval && row.isSelected==true) {
                   return "changecolor";
                 }
                 return "";
               };
               gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);                                              
          })  
       
       
       
       
       if($scope.resultSummary){
       $scope.gridapis[k].grid.modifyRows($scope.data['griddata'+k].data);         
    for(var i=0; i< $scope.selRows[k].length; i++){
     if($scope.selRows[k])
     gridApi.selection.selectRow(($scope.selRows[k])[i]);                                            
     }
       }
   
       

      }
    
    })
  };

  
 
  
  
  
  $scope.selRows=[];
  $scope.AllRowsData=[]
  $scope.submitEvents=function(){   
  $scope.resultSummary=false;
   angular.forEach($scope.gridapis,function(gridApi,key){ 
 
    $scope.AllRowsData.push($scope.data['griddata'+key].data)
    $scope.selRows[key]=gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();      
    $scope.data['griddata'+key].enableRowHeaderSelection = false;  
    $scope.gridapis[key].core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.OPTIONS);   
    $scope.data['griddata'+key].data=$scope.selRows[key];

 })  
  }
  
  $scope.backToResultSummary=function(){   
   $scope.resultSummary=true;   
   angular.forEach($scope.gridapis,function(gridApi,key){       
    $scope.data['griddata'+key].data=$scope.AllRowsData[key];              
    $scope.data['griddata'+key].enableRowHeaderSelection = true;
     gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.OPTIONS);
  })  
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  
  

 $scope.isActive=function(){
  
  
  return true
  
  
 }
  
 $scope.toggleAccord=function(){
  if($scope.isActive==true){
   $scope.isActive=false
  }
  
  if($scope.isActive==false){
   $scope.isActive=true
  }
 }
 

  
}]);







//JSON DATA


[
  {
    "EventName": "BONU CA00007986795 / 0031366-000 / Euroclear 96008",
    "col": [
      {
        "name": "EventID",
        "displayName": "EventID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Account ID",
        "displayName": "Account ID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Reference No",
        "displayName": "Reference No"
      },
      {
        "name": "Security",
        "displayName": "Security"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Type",
        "displayName": "Event Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Category",
        "displayName": "Event Category"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ex Date",
        "displayName": "Ex Date"
      },
      {
        "name": "Entitlement Method",
        "displayName": "Entitlement Method"
      },
      {
        "name": "Rate",
        "displayName": "Rate"
      },
      {
        "name": "Rate Per share",
        "displayName": "Rate Per share"
      },
      {
        "name": "Type",
        "displayName": "Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "Status",
        "displayName": "Status"
      },
      {
        "name": "Source",
        "displayName": "Source"
      }
    ],
    "record": [
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986795",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated/NV",
        "Rate": "1751",
        "Rate Per share": " ",
        "Type": "NEWM",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "EUROCLEAR"
      },
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986796",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated/NV",
        "Rate": "2751",
        "Rate Per share": " ",
        "Type": "NEWM",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "EUROCLEAR"
      },
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986797",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated/NV",
        "Rate": "2751",
        "Rate Per share": "275/109.31 USD",
        "Type": "NEWM",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "EUROCLEAR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EventName": "BONU CA00007986795 / 0022255-001 / Euroclear 96008",
    "col": [
      {
        "name": "EventID",
        "displayName": "EventID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Account ID",
        "displayName": "Account ID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Reference No",
        "displayName": "Reference No"
      },
      {
        "name": "Security",
        "displayName": "Security"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Type",
        "displayName": "Event Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Category",
        "displayName": "Event Category"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ex Date",
        "displayName": "Ex Date"
      },
      {
        "name": "Entitlement Method",
        "displayName": "Entitlement Method"
      },
      {
        "name": "Rate",
        "displayName": "Rate"
      },
      {
        "name": "Rate Per share",
        "displayName": "Rate Per share"
      },
      {
        "name": "Type",
        "displayName": "Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "Status",
        "displayName": "Status"
      },
      {
        "name": "Source",
        "displayName": "Source"
      }
    ],
    "record": [
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986795",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated/NV",
        "Rate": "1751",
        "Rate Per share": " ",
        "Type": "NEWM",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "EUROCLEAR"
      },
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986796",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated/NV",
        "Rate": "2751",
        "Rate Per share": " ",
        "Type": "REPE",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "EUROCLEAR"
      },
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986797",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated/NV",
        "Rate": "2751",
        "Rate Per share": "275/109.31 USD",
        "Type": "REPE",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "EUROCLEAR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EventName": "BONU CA00007986795 / 0045386-000 / Euroclear 96008",
    "col": [
      {
        "name": "EventID",
        "displayName": "EventID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Account ID",
        "displayName": "Account ID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Reference No",
        "displayName": "Reference No"
      },
      {
        "name": "Security",
        "displayName": "Security"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Type",
        "displayName": "Event Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Category",
        "displayName": "Event Category"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ex Date",
        "displayName": "Ex Date"
      },
      {
        "name": "Entitlement Method",
        "displayName": "Entitlement Method"
      },
      {
        "name": "Rate",
        "displayName": "Rate"
      },
      {
        "name": "Rate Per share",
        "displayName": "Rate Per share"
      },
      {
        "name": "Type",
        "displayName": "Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "Status",
        "displayName": "Status"
      },
      {
        "name": "Source",
        "displayName": "Source"
      }
    ],
    "record": [
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986795",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated/NV",
        "Rate": "1751",
        "Rate Per share": " ",
        "Type": "NEWM",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "EUROCLEAR"
      },
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986796",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated/NV",
        "Rate": "2751",
        "Rate Per share": " ",
        "Type": "NEWM",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "EUROCLEAR"
      },
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986797",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated/NV",
        "Rate": "2751",
        "Rate Per share": "275/109.31 USD",
        "Type": "NEWM",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "EUROCLEAR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EventName": "BONU CA00007986795 / 0019555-000 / Mitsubishi 87x564",
    "col": [
      {
        "name": "EventID",
        "displayName": "EventID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Account ID",
        "displayName": "Account ID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Reference No",
        "displayName": "Reference No"
      },
      {
        "name": "Security",
        "displayName": "Security"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Category",
        "displayName": "Event Category"
      },
      {
        "name": "Status",
        "displayName": "Status"
      },
      {
        "name": "Source",
        "displayName": "Source"
      }
    ],
    "record": [
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986795",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "DEVON ENERGY",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "Mitsubishi"
      },
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986796",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "DEVON ENERGY",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "Mitsubishi"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EventName": "INTR CA00007986777 / 0045390-000 / BNP Parib. Mill. 100960-208",
    "col": [
      {
        "name": "EventID",
        "displayName": "EventID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Account ID",
        "displayName": "Account ID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Reference No",
        "displayName": "Reference No"
      },
      {
        "name": "Security",
        "displayName": "Security"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Type",
        "displayName": "Event Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Category",
        "displayName": "Event Category"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ex Date",
        "displayName": "Ex Date"
      },
      {
        "name": "Entitlement Method",
        "displayName": "Entitlement Method"
      },
      {
        "name": "Amount",
        "displayName": "Amount"
      },
      {
        "name": "Balance",
        "displayName": "Balance"
      },
      {
        "name": "Type",
        "displayName": "Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "Status",
        "displayName": "Status"
      },
      {
        "name": "Source",
        "displayName": "Source"
      }
    ],
    "record": [
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986777",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "INTR",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated",
        "Amount": "10000",
        "Balance": "1000 /-",
        "Type": "NEWM",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "BNP Parib. Mill."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EventName": "INTR CA00007986777 / 0045500-000 / BNP Parib. Mill. 325043-450",
    "col": [
      {
        "name": "EventID",
        "displayName": "EventID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Account ID",
        "displayName": "Account ID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Reference No",
        "displayName": "Reference No"
      },
      {
        "name": "Security",
        "displayName": "Security"
      }
    ],
    "record": [
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986777",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC"
      },
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986778",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EventName": "INTR CA00007986777 / 0055555-000 / BNP Parib. Mill. 104444-477",
    "col": [
      {
        "name": "EventID",
        "displayName": "EventID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Account ID",
        "displayName": "Account ID"
      },
      {
        "name": "Reference No",
        "displayName": "Reference No"
      },
      {
        "name": "Security",
        "displayName": "Security"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Type",
        "displayName": "Event Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "Event Category",
        "displayName": "Event Category"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ex Date",
        "displayName": "Ex Date"
      },
      {
        "name": "Entitlement Method",
        "displayName": "Entitlement Method"
      },
      {
        "name": "Amount",
        "displayName": "Amount"
      },
      {
        "name": "Balance",
        "displayName": "Balance"
      },
      {
        "name": "Type",
        "displayName": "Type"
      },
      {
        "name": "Status",
        "displayName": "Status"
      },
      {
        "name": "Source",
        "displayName": "Source"
      }
    ],
    "record": [
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986795",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated",
        "Amount": "10000",
        "Balance": "397.50 USD",
        "Type": "REPE",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "BNP Parib. Mill."
      },
      {
        "EventID": "CA00007986796",
        "Account ID": "NBL0178529",
        "Reference No": "US0378331005",
        "Security": "APPLE INC",
        "Event Type": "BONU",
        "Event Category": "MAND",
        "Ex Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Entitlement Method": "Calculated",
        "Amount": "10000",
        "Balance": "397.50 USD",
        "Type": "NEWM",
        "Status": "Released",
        "Source": "BNP Parib. Mill."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<input ng-if="resultSummary" type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="submitEvents()">
<input ng-if="!resultSummary" type="button" value="Back" ng-click="backToResultSummary()">
      <accordion close-others="false">
        <accordion-group is-open="isActive"  ng-click="toggleAccord()" ng-repeat="obj in data"  ng-if="data['griddata'+$index].data.length>0">
          <accordion-heading>
            {{EventList[$index].EventName}}
           
          </accordion-heading>            
          <div  ng-if="resultSummary" class="grid"  style="width:1570px;background-color:white;" ui-grid-edit   ui-grid-move-columns  ui-grid="data['griddata'+$index]" 
             ui-grid-selection>
          </div>
          <div ng-if="!resultSummary" class="grid"  style="width:1570px;background-color:white;" ui-grid-edit   ui-grid-move-columns  ui-grid="data['griddata'+$index]" 
             >
          </div>
   
        </accordion-group>
 
      </accordion>
```

I have two ui grids.In first Ui grid i have a afteredit listener which changes color of a cell by columndef cellclass if cell is edited.

Suppose i have edited few cells in grid and that cells color changed.

Now i want to display the rows of first grid along with the changed color...Iam able to display the rows but im unable to change cellclass of second because i dont know where to start.

Note:-im using dynamic multiple ui grids.
Columndef is dynamically given.so i cant write cellclass in columndef.we have to set it programatically

Comment: Would you kindly post a minimum working example (MWE) of your code, so that people can see clearly what you are asking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can begin with

```
cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{ \'my-css-class\':grid.appScope.rowFormatter(row) }"> ... '
```

where `rowFormatter` should be a function that has to be attached to scope in the controller:

```
$scope.rowFormatter = function(row) {
    return row.entity.gender === 'male';
};
```